# What is known about NP hard problems that access preprocessed information?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, sat, oracles

Please accept my apologies ahead of time since I fear that this isn't an adequate question for cstheory.  I plan on releasing my ideas to get feedback, but I don't know if my target audience will include state-of-the-art reaseachers.  I'd like to know more about the research that is already out there concerning this question.

Essentially, what I think I've discovered is an oracle.  The oracle must be precomputed, which will probably take an exponential amount of time.  However, once computed, it can essentially answer any question about 3-SAT fast.  In other words, it can then solve any 3-SAT problem in polynomial time/space.  I'm wondering what has been researched in this scenario.

**MY ORIGINAL QUESTION**

As an armchair cstheory enthusiast, I'm now working on a way to preprocess 3-SAT.  I'm wondering how this relates to research on oracles and related ideas.  Please let me briefly describe my method, or conjectured approach.

We take a given problem size.  Essentially we have exactly $2^n$ clauses and $v$ variables.  (Note that problems smaller than this can automatically be solved, too.)  After we know the maximum amount of clauses, we can preprocess information for every possible 3-SAT clause, given the information just stated.  This may take an exponential amount of information, even for each individual clause.

However, once the information is preprocessed, we can solve 3-SAT fast.  In other words, using this pre-computed database, which is polynomial in size, we can determine satisfiability for a particular instance as well as generate a certificate in polynomial time and space.

So if I'm correct, we use an oracle and we can ensure that 3-SAT can be solved in polynomial time and space.  However, the oracle itself takes a possibly exponential amount of time and space to compute.

My question is where in the literature can I find information concerning pre-computing information (like I have described) to solve NP-hard and NP-complete problems in polynomial time and space?  What is known about this approach?  I don't mean to be vague, but I'm simply trying to find out what has been considered about an approach like this in the past.  I plan on eventually releasing my ideas if they are interesting, but I would like to know if they have already been researched.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Precomputation is often related to the class [P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P/poly)[/poly](http://qwiki.stanford.edu/index.php/Complexity_Zoo%3aP#ppoly) which captures problems solvable in polynomial time by Turing machines with access to some poly-sized *advice string*, that only depends on the *size* of the instance, but not the instance itself. The [Karp-Lipton theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karp%E2%80%93Lipton_theorem) states, that NP is not contained in P/poly, unless the PH collapses to the second level, which is considered unlikely by many complexity theorists.

Comment: To be more precise, the oracle counts the total number of satisfying solutions, and returns this number mod p  - see this question: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/9319.

Comment: Then you're asking about what can be solved in $\mathsf{P^{\oplus P}}$ ?

Comment: @Suresh Venkat: I realized that my idea fails for large enough problems.  I guess that would have been in $P^{⊕P}$.